# Laravel, Admin controllers - 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create Admin controllers in the default controller folder. I have created "admin" folder in the "controller" folder.

In the routes file:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'admin/AdminController@showAdminIndex');
```

AdminController.php file:

```
namespace Admin;

class AdminController extends \BaseController {

    public function showAdminIndex()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

I get an error on the browser:

```
403 Forbidden
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Do you happen to have an `admin` directory in the `public` folder?

Comment: @lukasgeiter There is a `admin` directory in the public folder

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Maybe you should remove `admin/` from `'admin/AdminController@showAdminIndex'`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you have an `admin` subfolder in the `public` directory. The `.htaccess` that ships with Laravel only boots the application if no directory or file exists at the requested URI (that's why CSS and other assets still work)

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You basically have two options here:

1. Rename either one, the route or the folder. If `public/admin` is for assets you could put it in `public/assets/admin` for example.
2. Change your `.htaccess` to not ignore folders for rewriting

Like:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`
```