# 403 Forbidden Laravel on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, admin, shared-hosting, voyager

I have a shared hosting and I'm trying to make my laravel project works on it, I'm using voyager to the admin panel.

I put my app public folder inside the /public_html and the rest of the project on the same level of the /public_html, so it looks like this:

```
.bash_history
.bash_logout
.bash_profile
.bashrc
.cache
.cpanel
.htpasswds
logs
mail
app -> my project
public_ftp
public_html -> where my app public folder is
.ssh
tmp
etc
...
```

I have managed to work almost everything, but the admin panel is not working properly.

When I access www.example.com/admin it goes to www.example.com/admin/login, I put my credentials and submit the form, after it returns to the same page, then I checked the network tab on Chrome and it appears the following message:

```
Request URL: http://example.com/admin/login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
```

Anybody knows how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: is all permissions correct?

Comment: I set 775 to storage and vendors folder, is it correct?

Comment: That's not how it should be. You entire Laravel project should reside in `public_html` including the `public` folder. Then you can write some `.htaccess` rule to point to your domain root `public folder.`

Answer (score 9):

If you get any issue like that, then add `.htaccess` file in root folder, and put below code in that, it will start working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: worked with me on namecheap

Comment: what is namecheap ?

Comment: my host plane on this https://www.namecheap.com/

Comment: works for me for wave saas starter kit

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you should copy your files of public folder to the public_html folder and put other folders outside of public_html because it is available to the whole world.

You should modify the public/index.php file will following details:

```
//line 24
require __DIR__.'/../app/vendor/autoload.php';

// line 38
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap/app.php';
```

## Since you have public folder inside public_html folder, you should add one more (..)

```
//line 24
require __DIR__.'/../../app/vendor/autoload.php';

// line 38
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../app/bootstrap/app.php';
```

## Domain or subdomain

Point your domain or subdomain to {{your_domain}}/public

```
eg: In your case, if you visit www.abc.com it should point to /public_html/public.
for other cases, it should point to /public_html
```

## Note:

Don't forget to update your .env file

1. set APP_ENV=production
2. APP_DEBUG=false
3. LOG_CHANNEL=daily // considered good practice
4. Your database credentials
5. And other necessary changes...

## Permissions

Normally you don't need to change files and folder permission. If you need to then set Folders to 755 and files to 644

> ## Never set permission to 777

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was due to the `.htaccess` looking for a folder (that was forbidden) instead of using the Laravel route with the same name `/admin`.

See StackOverflow here : 
[Laravel, Admin controllers - 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457280/laravel-admin-controllers-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi your storage folder must be set permission 777 
chmod -R 777
OR
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www (recomended)

Comment: -R 777 yes but www-data is okay )

Comment: Never set permission to 777

Comment: why ?, if it local machine.

Comment: And for your information my recommended way to solve this issue this 
```sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www (recomended)``` as I mention in my response