# "403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access" in the laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

All ajax request are failing with 403 Forbidden error. Is it due to htaccess. I am having this issue after hosting it on the server.I have changed the .htaccess as below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php
    RewriteEngine On
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

I am having public files in public_html and other folders on the root directory.

I am having the files in the path API\MyContorller and the route
 `Route::apiResources(['post' => 'API\MyContorller ]);`

I am having this issue with XHR Request i.e Ajax Call Put Request

I am calling update method to update the table in the vue Component

```
 updateQuiz(){
            this.form.put('/api/chapter/'+this.$route.params.id + '/quiz/' + this.form.id);

}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696539/put-request-403-forbidden) if helps?

Answer (score 2):

Remember about CSRF token in requests.

If your'e using PUT/DELETE method, you can transform this to

```
{
method: 'POST',
data: { _method: 'PUT', _token: token },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anybody get into this trouble . Here is the solution add below code to your htaccess file in the public folder

```
<Limit GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
    Require all granted
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
    Require all denied
</LimitExcept>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hosting which have web server mapping to root directory, your htaccess file should contains request redirect to public/index.php file 
e.g.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I am having pubiic_html folder instead of public

Comment: Do I need to add this on the htaccess

Comment: Read this topic maybe help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292963/403-forbidden-laravel-on-shared-hosting

Comment: There is some changes you need to add in index.php file

Comment: Show how you call request.

Problem exists with GET, POST methods ? Or only with PUT/DELETE ?

Comment: Only with Put/Delete

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it turns out not doing `git init` before is the actual cause of this problem. It doesn't matter if you have already hooked the project to a GitHub repository. Make sure u do a `git init` at the beginning and then do a `git add .` before u commit and push